# CSS Fading Slideshow Initial Images Stuck

Tags: html, css, animation, slideshow, timing

I grabbed the code from **[here](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/)** and altered it for my slideshow. In my slideshow it fades each image in and out completely.

My problem is only that in the beginning all the PNG images are stacked on top of each other. I have a pattern back drop on the original project. And I have to only use HTML and CSS3 as such like is already here. I'm creating a slideshow for Confluence and I am restricted to do it all in a "body" tag.

Any insights appreciated.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<!--

For "n" images You must define:
a=presentation time for one image
b=duration for cross fading
Total animation-duration is of course t=(a+b)*n

animation-delay = t/n or = a+b

Percentage for keyframes:

0%
a/t*100%
(a+b)/t*100% = 1/n*100%
100%-(b/t*100%)
100%
-->



<body>
    <style>

        @-webkit-keyframes slideshowFadeInOut {
            0% {
                opacity: 1;
            }

            10.4% {
                opacity: 1;
            }

            12.5% {
                opacity: 0;
            }

            98% {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }

        @-moz-keyframes slideshowFadeInOut {
            0% {
                opacity: 1;
            }

            10.4% {
                opacity: 1;
            }

            12.5% {
                opacity: 0;
            }

            98% {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }

        @-o-keyframes slideshowFadeInOut {
            0% {
                opacity: 1;
            }

            10.4% {
                opacity: 1;
            }

            12.5% {
                opacity: 0;
            }

            98% {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }

        @keyframes slideshowFadeInOut {
            0% {
                opacity: 1;
            }

            10.4% {
                opacity: 1;
            }

            12.5% {
                opacity: 0;
            }

            98% {
                opacity: 0;
            }
            100% {
                opacity: 1;
            }
        }

        #overview-slideshow {
            position: relative;
            height: 300px;
            width: 300px;
        }

        #overview-slideshow img {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
        }

        #overview-slideshow img {
            --duration: 24s;
            -webkit-animation-name: slideshowFadeInOut;
            -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
            -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            -webkit-animation-duration: var(--duration);

            -moz-animation-name: slideshowFadeInOut;
            -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
            -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            -moz-animation-duration: var(--duration);

            -o-animation-name: slideshowFadeInOut;
            -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
            -o-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            -o-animation-duration: var(--duration);

            animation-name: slideshowFadeInOut;
            animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
            animation-iteration-count: infinite;
            animation-duration: var(--duration);
        }

        #overview-slideshow img:nth-of-type(1) {
            --delay: 21s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            -moz-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            -o-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            animation-delay: var(--delay);
        }

        #overview-slideshow img:nth-of-type(2) {
            --delay: 18s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            -moz-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            -o-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            animation-delay: var(--delay);
        }

        #overview-slideshow img:nth-of-type(3) {
            --delay: 15s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            -moz-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            -o-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            animation-delay: var(--delay);
        }

        #overview-slideshow img:nth-of-type(4) {
            --delay: 12s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            -moz-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            -o-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            animation-delay: var(--delay);
        }
        
        #overview-slideshow img:nth-of-type(5) {
            --delay: 9s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            -moz-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            -o-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            animation-delay: var(--delay);
        }
        
        #overview-slideshow img:nth-of-type(6) {
            --delay: 6s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            -moz-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            -o-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            animation-delay: var(--delay);
        }
        
        #overview-slideshow img:nth-of-type(7) {
            --delay: 3s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            -moz-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            -o-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            animation-delay: var(--delay);
        }
        
        #overview-slideshow img:nth-of-type(8) {
            --delay: 0s;
            -webkit-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            -moz-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            -o-animation-delay: var(--delay);
            animation-delay: var(--delay);
        }

    </style>


    <div id="overview-slideshow" class="shadow">
        <img src="blank.png">
        <img src="Iso.png">
        <img src="blank.png">
        <img src="Top.png">
        <img src="blank.png">
        <img src="Front.png">
        <img src="blank.png">
        <img src="Side.png">
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the same resource as you to create the slideshow. For me, the images quickly load in succession before the slideshow starts. Is that what is happening to you?

My solution was to give each of the images a different z-index so that they are loading behind the first:

```
img:nth-of-type(1) {
    z-index: 3;
}

img:nth-of-type(2) {
    z-index: 2;
}
img:nth-of-type(3) {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I hope this helps.